# facebook comments in django: url unreachable warning

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So, I have this small django blog (django newbie here) I have made (as per thr tutorials of django) and I then decided to add facebook comments to this. So, I went to the [plugin page of facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) and did a "get code". Now, my page looks like so:

```
<body>

{% block facebookcomments %}
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=375557716230123";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
{% endblock facebookcomments %}
```

and then, in the places where I need the comments to show up, I first declare the meta content required by facebook like so:

```
{% block metacontent %}
    {{ block.super }}
<meta property="og:site_name" content="first django blog" >
<meta property="og:type" content="website" >
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ detailobject.title|truncatechars:50 }}" >
{% if "None found" not in detailobject.blog_desc %}
<meta property="og:description" content="
{{ detailobject.blog_desc|truncatechars:100 }}" >
{% else %}
<meta property="og:description" content="
blog description goes here {{ detailobject.title|truncatechars:100 }}" >
{% endif %}
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}" >
<meta property="og:image" content="{% static 'docs/assets/ico/fbcomments.png' %}" >
{% endblock metacontent %}
```

and finally, the comments plugin is initialized like so:

```
 <div class="fb-comments" 
 data-href = "{{ request.build_absolute_uri|urlencode:"" }}" 
 data-width = "600" 
 data-num-posts = "10"
 colorscheme = "light">
 </div>
```

..the problem is, on everypage I have facebook comments, I get an annoying message at the bottom of the comments plugin saying:

```
"Warning URL "...." is unreachable"
```

where `"..."` is the URL of the page.

I have tried debugging it to no effect (there are no error or warning messages for the page on fb debugger - initially it said it needed og:url etc.. once I fixed them, I see no errors/warning on fb debugger, but the warning still remains).

When I refresh the page the warning disappears!

I am totally confused now how to get rid of this error. The funny thing is that I do not get this warning on my devel environment - but get this in production type environment.

I would really appreciate if anyone could guide me in the right direction to solve this issue. I am beginning to think that I am not using the FB Javascriot SDK correctly - not sure if all I need is the JS code above or if I need to include it as shown [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

Comment: What is the actual value of data-href in the generated HTML? It sounds like that's where your problem is.

Comment: thanks so much for the tip. The generated data-href is as follows: `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.domainname.com%2Fmy-blog%2Fdetail-jan-100-107-6311451130372319%2F`. I use `{{ request.build_absolute_uri|urlencode:"" }}` in django/python to generate this url. Now I see on facebook debugger: `Object at URL 'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.domainname.com%2Fmy-blog%2FFdetail-jan-100-107-6311451130372319%2F' of type 'null' is invalid because the given value 'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.domainname.com%2Fmy-blog%2FFdetail-jan-100-107-6311451130372319%2F' for property 'og:url' could not be parsed as type 'og:url'.`

Comment: I think the problem is that you've encoded the URLs when you shouldn't do. Try taking out ```|urlencode:""``` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @MatthewDaly: Well if I try it without the `urlencode:""` I have data-href as `https://www.domainname.com/my-blog/detail-jan-100-107-6311451130372319/`. No facebook errors then but it still displays the warning `Warning URL .. cannot be reached` really weird!

Comment: Is the facebookcomments block being rendered?

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://github.com/matthewbdaly/Djibouti/blob/master/djibouti/templates/layout/base.html and https://github.com/matthewbdaly/Djibouti/blob/master/djibouti/templates/blog/post_detail.html - these were for a Django blog I wrote that included Facebook comments, so maybe comparing them will help identify the issue.

Comment: yes, the facebookcomments block does render. It is surprising - I have pretty much the same code as you - my detailview code is here for example:http://pastebin.com/HduVsaY6 not sure how its any different to yours :( I am beginning to think maybe its something to do with https. Also, I was wondering if I need to include `fbinit` as shown here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ ..At the moment I only have the code as posted here (I see that you have the same).

Comment: @MatthewDaly: Hi Matt, I was just wondering if you could confirm if your code works. By the looks of it, it looks like a facebook bug: http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Facebook-Comments-URL-Unreachable-Error-3152364.S.228233499 Also, I was wondering..on the facebook developer site, I do not need to fill out "App on Facebook" details - do I? Many thanks for all your help!

Comment: Yes, it works in my case - see example at http://blog.shellshocked.info/2013/7/running-php-development-server-laravel/ .

Comment: @MatthewDaly: VERY strange that the exact same code does not work for me:( starting to think it could be the urlconf backslash at the end of a url. At the moment I have something like: `url(r'^blog-detail/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$', AllBlogsDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),`

Comment: Try hard-coding the URL to http://example.com and see if that works. Facebook comments always relate to a specific URL and that's the one used by the example on the Comments Box page in Facebook's documentation. If that doesn't work that'll rule out the URL being the issue